# How do I add thousand separators in default number format in ssrs?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I got a bunch of numbers in different unit. I need to add thousand commas separators without affecting the decimal values. I want the decimal values to display as it is.
I want the number format in following way

> - 10000     ---> 10,000
> - 56789.125 ---> 56,789.125
> - 2000.1231 ---> 2,000.1231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SSRS (right click text box-expression), specify this expression value:

```
=Format(Fields!ColumnName.Value, "#,###0.####")
```

This will format your number into maximum 4 digits on decimal point, depending on presence of decimal values after the point.

If you need to format number value from C# code before adding to SSRS, use:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###0.####}", ColumnName.ToString()); // assume ColumnName is your number variable here
```

Custom numeric formatting reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the simplest way:

```
myInteger.ToString("N0")
```

Or you can do like so:

```
myInteger.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
static string FormatNumber(int num)
 {    
    return num.ToString("#,0");
 }
```